# How to delete duplicated Objects from SQLite query result from android

Tags: android, sqlite, activeandroid

what I am trying to do is delete the duplicates from a query result.
I tried to use HashSet but did not quite work. So I am trying to delete the duplicates from the query directly.

This is the query

```
public List<SaleHeader> getSaleHeadersDevolutionsToSync(){
    List<SaleHeader> saleHeaderList =new Select().from(SaleHeader.class)
            .innerJoin(Devolution.class)
            .on("Devolutions.idSaleHeader = SaleHeaders.idSaleHeader")
            .where("Devolutions.idDevolution < 0").execute();
    Log.e("Tag", String.valueOf(saleHeaderList));
    return saleHeaderList;
}
```

This is the HashSet I tried

```
            Set<SaleHeader> set = new HashSet<>(saleHeaderDevolutionList);
            saleHeaderDevolutionList.clear();
            saleHeaderDevolutionList.addAll(set);
```

Any help or sugestions on what to look for would be great, thanks

Comment: new HashSet<TYPE???>.....

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that too, but android mark it as unnecessary. Anyway I let it there and did not work either

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figure it out on how to implement a direct query

```
    List<SaleHeader> saleHeaderListQuery =
            SQLiteUtils.rawQuery(SaleHeader.class,
                    "SELECT DISTINCT Devolutions.idsaleheader FROM Devolutions LEFT JOIN SaleHeaders ON Devolutions.idSaleHeader = SaleHeaders.idsaleheader " +
                            "WHERE Devolutions.iddevolution < ?",
                    new String[] { "0" });
```